# Is there a way to export a query or table from BigQuery in .txt format?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have to deposit a report in .txt format once a day and upload it to an SFTP. I have generated the report in BigQuery but can't find a way to export it as .txt. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a number of ways to accomplish this and almost all involve some extend of coding with clients of your choice or great GCP tools like Dataflow, etc.  They all require skilled engineers at hand

For sure, there will be few answers covering those options

Meantime, I want to provide different option.
There are some third party tools that helps to achieve same w/o no extra coding (rather than BigQuery querying)

Below is example of how simple it is to do with [Magnus](https://potensio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/115000401632-Magnus) which is part of [Potens.io](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio) suite of powerful and efficient tools for BigQuery designed so that even the non-engineer can easily explore and automate workflows to become self-sufficient in their data needs like in your question.
***Disclosure***: Google Developer Expert in Cloud here - author of BigQuery Mate and Potens.io (Magnus and Goliath) productivity tools

So, in below screenshot you see workflow with just two Tasks.

[image]

First Task defines payload of your report and Second Task uploads it to client's SFTP

Below you can see flip side of second task with more settings - zero coding!

[image]

In this particular example  - you do not even need to persist your report in BQ Table - Second Task will just pick it from the first Task (even though obviously in real life you most likely to preserve report  - which is still easy to set in first Task using Destination Entry)

I recommend you to try